# how to refactor this with ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I might not need to refactor this code but now I'm just curious how to do it.

```
  handleError: ({ error, email, password }, props) => authError => {
    if (email === "" || password === "") {
      return {
        error: `Fields can't be empty`
      };
    } else {
      return {
        error: authError
      };
    }
  }
```

this doesn't provide the same functionality as the code above:

```
  handleError: ({ error, email, password }, props) => authError => {
    email === "" || password === ""
      ? { error: `Fields can't be empty` }
      : { error: authError };
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any return. Since the only conditional logic is the message, it can be simplified as below.

```
handleError: ({ error, email, password }, props) => (authError) => ({
  error: email === "" || password === "" ? `Fields can't be empty` : authError
})
```

Instead of return, you can wrap your object in parenthesis.

Comment: Upvoted since explanation has been added and given a nice alternative :)

Comment: Then accept the answer you find most valuable :) Shame that we can only accept one answer. But, upvotes are for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the `return`
It should be:

```
handleError: ({ error, email, password }, props) => authError => {
  return email === "" || password == ""
    ? { error: `Fields can't be empty` }
    : { error: authError };
};
```

Comment: Upvoted, since this is the only answer that explaining why the OP's code is not working.

Comment: or, enclose the returned object in `()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
handleError: ({ error, email, password }, props) => authError => {
    return email === "" || password === "" ? {error: "Fields can't be empty"} : {error: authError};
}
```